# In dialog window scroll while dragging with jquery's Drag-n-Drop doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Problem:
when I'm dragging inside of dialog box(look link image), Afganistan is the country that i'm dragging to bottom, when drag reaches bottom of this dialog box it's not autoscrolling.

code I wrote:

```
function popUpCountries(url, widthWin, heightWin, title) {
    $("#dialog").dialog('destroy').html('<img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="/system/ext/jquery/progbar.gif" alt="[[Please wait ...]]" />Please wait ...');
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: widthWin,
        height: heightWin,
        title: title,
        position : "center"
    }).dialog('open');

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $("#dialog").html(data);
    });
```

image : http://postimg.org/image/cgcr0j32f/
I'm using jqueryUI dialog, dialog box's css position:absolute.
thanks for any help!

Comment: A lotta people are fighting for Afghanistan buddy! ;)

Comment: no seriosly, i need that help, i'm trying to do it almost a week.

Comment: Are u using draggable? Have you tried setting the option `refreshPositions: true` for it?

Comment: Vandesh, yes i tried it, didnt help